# ghost characther appearing from firebase

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have a piece of code retrieving a value from my firebase db. 
But for some reason it appears to insert a comma into my input from out of nowhere.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("2018/teams_sea/");
$( "#nr" ).change(function( event ) {
var data = document.getElementById('nr').value
  ref.orderByKey()
  .equalTo(data)
  .once('value')
  .then(function (snapshot) {
   document.getElementById('name').value = snapshot.val();
})
```

});

```
If I replace:
   document.getElementById('name').value = snapshot.val();
with 
 document.getElementById('name').value = "test";
```

The comma does not appear, so I am fairly certain that it comes from firebase somehow, but it is not in the DB when I am looking in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's because you fire a query, but fail to handle the fact that is has potentially multiple results. I recommend switching out the query, which is useless here anyway:

```
ref.child(data)
  .once('value')
  .then(function (snapshot) {
   document.getElementById('name').value = snapshot.val();
})
```

Comment: Simplified and useful, now it works! I am really grateful for your help. Thank you